# How to loop a set of commands for a list of hosts?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a set of commands in my batch file, for expample:

```
-connect to host %%
-net stop service1
-net start service1
-servicestatus >>c:\temporary\servicestatus.txt

(%% = parameter)
```

I made a text file that contains the list of the host names and i want my batch to run for every host in that file.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: How should i do that?

Comment: Well, you would need to make the question a little more clear, then I can help. What do you plan to use to connect to host? What format is your file? etc etc.

Comment: I have a service that runs on all of the hosts and the command resets automatically when im connecting to a new host. My batch is in .bat format, and my hosts list is in .txt format.

Comment: Still unclear, I cannot guess this service, does it have have its own shell?

Comment: Ill make it clearer. The connection is not the problem, i do it every time i need to from cmd in my server. The problem is - how to loop a set of ANY commands for a list of hosts that written in txt external file and not inside the script itself?

Comment: Thank you, please specify exactly the inpout, expected output, service you use etc.. As an example, show how you do a manual connection, run services and disconnect.

Comment: But thats not my point.. im trying to figure only how to loop a set of command for external list of hosts written on txt file

Comment: So that is all you want to know?

Comment: Yes, that is the only problem i have in this specific situation

Comment: Well, there you go... see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, you simply want to know how to loop through something, in this case a file:

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in (hostnames.txt) do (
  echo %%i
  other commands goes here...
)
```

You can remove the `echo %%i` line, as it is simply there to show you how it will read the file.
This assumes that your `hostnames.txt` files looks something like this:

```
hostname1
somePC-02
Server123
```

*NOTE!* If however your service executes a seperate shell, it will not initiate the commands as cmd will not be able to access that shell.